# Material ui: How to change AM and PM background color of TimePicker calendar?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the Material UI DatePicker time AM & PM button color.
I tried to change I want to create a custom style and I have created but it work only on label, text & calendar icon, its not working on datetimepicker dialogbox.

```
 const DateTextField = styled(TextField)(({ theme }) => ({
        color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        "& .MuiIconButton-root": {
          padding: 0, 
          }, 
          components: {
            MuiIconButton: {
              styleOverrides: {
                sizeMedium: {
                  color
                }
              }
            },
            MuiOutlinedInput: {
              styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                  color
                }
              }
            },
            MuiInputLabel: {
              styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                  color
                }
              }
            }
          }
        
    }));
    
<LocalizationProvider sx={{ borderColor: "#FFF" }} dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                        <FastField
                          component={CssDateTimePicker}
                          label='Start Date*'
                          name='start_at'
                          id='start_at'
                          format={"MM/DD/YYYY"}
                          color="primary"
                          value={values.start_at}
                          minDateTime={new Date()}
                          onChange={(newValue) => {
                            if (errors.start_at) {
                              setFieldTouched("start_at", true)
                            }
                            setFieldValue("start_at", newValue);
                          }}
                          inputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
                          disablePast={true}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <DateTextField
                              {...params}
                              autoComplete={"Off"}
                              size='small'
                            />
                          )}
                        />
                      </LocalizationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 5 of MUI try to add this =>
sx={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }} to TextField in renderInput prop.

Comment: this is working on textbox and I want to some other like when I click calendar icon that time open calendar box if select the date then it open the time box and inside time dialogbox  we are showing am and pm so that time I want change the bgcolor of am and pm.

Comment: If I understand correctly you should try this, Create an MuiTheme, and override the MuiTimePickers backgroundColor property.
After that wrap your component with ThemeProvider.